# How to store these dbusername,dbpassword after login in play framework?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a separate `dbusername` and `dbpassword` for each login user in a Play framework Scala application. Login credentials are first checked by against a stored Postgres database username and password. After a successful login it gets the user's `dbusername` and `dbpassword`, and connects to the database. How should I store the `dbusername` and `dbpassword` after login in the Play framework? Can I use global variables?

Comment: Why do you want to store them if they are already in the postgres DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify what you are doing here:

1. You are using Postgres user credentials as your Play application
   user credentials.
2. Database connections are authenticated with the user credentials, so you must be using database access control (i.e. `GRANT`s) for permissioning.

The first one is fine. The second is not, as it is not compatible with connection pooling. You would have to either: have a private connection pool per user (too many connections to your Postgres server), or open a new connection for every database access (slow). If your application will have more than a few users, I strongly recommend using the default database configuration in Play (single username/password in `application.conf`), which will use the built-in Play connection pool (i.e. the boneCP plugin). With this configuration, you would have a Postgres username/password for your Play application. You will have to implement permissioning in a different way.

To actually answer your question, here's the way to store information for a logged-in user:

1. On successful login, store a session id in the Play [session](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaSessionFlash) (*not* the user name, the session cookie is not encrypted).
2. Store the user information in the [cache](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaCache), using the session id as part of the key. The cache is really a big global variable, so you were right about needing that!
3. For each request, check if the session id is in the session. If not, the user is not logged in, so redirect to the login page. If the session id is valid but not in the cache, the session has expired, so redirect to login.

**Update**: if you have a small set of database credentials (corresponding to user roles), you can just use normal Play database configuration as follows:

1.In `application.conf`, create a set of db config settings, one for each role. For example:

```
db.guest.driver=org.postgres.???
db.guest.url=???
db.guest.user=theguest
db.guest.password=secret
```

2.At login, look up the user role, and store it in the cached session, as above. Then get the database connection using the connection name, like this:

```
val role = getRoleFromSession(request) // e.g. role = "guest"
play.api.db.DB.withConnection(role) { implicit c => ... }
```

Comment: In my case,I have 3 database username,password.Based on play application user credentials I pick a database username,password and try to store it local.Then open a new connection for every database access with the local username,password(As I fetched now).

Comment: Ah, if you have a small, fixed set of db credentials then you can just use Play connection names -- I'll update my answer.

Comment: @ Richard Close Actually I create 3 Roles dynamically for each SignUp in my Play Application.So I will have multiple of 3 db credentials.I think it is not possible to add static db credentials in application.conf. I have an idea,1)Check play app login credentials as postgres user 2)Get db credentials of logged in user 3) Write db user,password dynamically in application.conf using ConfigFactory 4) On logout remove the credentials from conf file. Is it good way? or can I use Global varaibles or cache ?

Comment: Writing `application.conf` will definitely not work! Play will not re-read .conf file. Better just to store db credentials in cache, as described. With (`3 * # of users`) separate db connections, you will have scaling problems, and cannot use connection pool. Strongly recommend you change your design to only use 1-3 database credentials total.

Answer (score -1):

You should put the username/passwd into a configuration file, and use `com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory` to load that info at runtime.

Comment: Pretty sure this would mean both that you can't hash the un/pw or otherwise make the credentials secure at rest, and that you'd have to rewrite and reload your configuration every time you added a user or changed either their un or pw.